# Texture issue with .obj files in material preview and rendering

Tags: texturing

I just recently started to use Blender to make Roblox gfx. I have been trying to use two models in my gfx for a little while. However, whenever I use the material preview mode the textures mesh together, and I'm not sure how to explain it. I import both of the .obj files how I usually would and everything is fine until I use the material preview mode. I have been trying to find a solution on youtube and reddit but haven't been successful. [image]

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. It only works 5% of the time and I don't know how to make that percentage go up.

If anyone has any tips please let me know!!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures